# How to set an empty UIStackView inside a UIScrollView so that i can fill it on runtime?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to set an empty vertical UIStackView inside a UIScrollView so that I can fill the UIStackView dynamically on runtime

I tried the solution given by apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html) but when I do that, the Auto Layout tool tells me that there is a missing constraint which is either the Y position or the height of the UIStackView.
The only difference I have between my UIScrollView and the one from the example is that I don't add a button inside the UIStackView.

When I fill the UIStackView on runtime, the logs say it has to break some constraints and then the UIScrollView fills the screen all the way to the bottom, pushing other views I had there out of sight.

Is this the right way to accomplish what I want? Or is there any other solution?

EDIT:

This is what I have, the logo constraint is only aspect ratio relative to itself

[image: Current status]

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @AndréSlotta I just added them

Comment: I set up a sample project and everything works as expected. You can compare it to your setup: https://ibb.co/QHmRvkp.

Comment: This is really weird. I'll remove everything and do it all over again to see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your constraints as you have them, but ***without*** the empty stack view in the scroll view.

Next:

- add a `UIStackView` to the scroll view
- constrain all 4 sides of the stack view to the scroll view
- constrain the stack view width equal to the scroll view width
- constrain the stack view height equal to the scroll view height

IB should show all constraints satisfied.

Then - and here's the key - edit the stack view's **Height** constraint and set it to be a Placeholder:

[image]

This Height constraint will now be removed at Build-Time. Any elements you add via code as `arrangedSubviews` will determine the height of the stack view, which will, in turn, define the vertical scrollable area (the `.contentSize`) --- all handled by auto-layout.